# Convert many values of a categorical column python

Tags: python, pandas

I had to recently map many categories in one data frame column into a few higher subcategories. I was wondering if there is a more concise way to achieve this as 
the one below.

```
df_to_map = pd.DataFrame({"cities": [ 'Thessaloniki', 'Geel', 'Bern', 'Dublin', 'Hanover' ,
 'Gurabo','Buenos Aires','Manati' ,'Panama', 'Lima', 
'Washington', 'Huston', 'Kairo']})

Aggregate_cities={
 'Thessaloniki':'Europe', 'Geel':'Europe', 'Bern':'Europe', 'Dublin':'Europe', 'Hanover':'Europe',
 'Gurabo':'Latin America','Manati' :'Latin America', 'Panama':'Latin America', 'Lima': 'Latin America' ,'Buenos Aires': 'Latin America', 
'Washington':'North America', 'Huston':'North America', 'Boston': 'North America'
 }

df_to_map['continent']= df_to_map.cities.map(Aggregate_cities)
```

Comment: I think it is really good and fast solution ;)

Comment: Would it be possible to put e.g. all the European cities in one list. Something like this  Aggregate_cities={ ['Thessaloniki , 'Geel', 'Bern', 'Dublin', 'Hanover']:'Europe'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as speed as concerned, agreed with @jezrael that you currently have just about the fastest solution for this problem.

However, you commented,

> Would it be possible to put all the European cities in one list?

Yes, if you want to, form a dictionary with reversed key/value structure:

```
Aggregate_cities = {
    'Europe' : ['Thessaloniki', 'Geel', 'Bern', 'Dublin', 'Hanover'],
    'Latin Ameriac': ['Gurabo', 'Manati', 'Panama', 'Lima', 'Buenos Aires'],
    'North America' : ['Washington', 'Huston', 'Boston']
    }
```

Then map your Series to the reverse of this:

```
df_to_map['continent']= df_to_map.cities.map(
    {v: k for k, cities in Aggregate_cities.items() for v in cities})
```

Is this faster?  No, because your current solution doesn't require this reversal through dictionary comprehension.  But perhaps this is more readable and easier to maintain.

What you **cannot** do is [use a list of cities as the keys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) in your dictionary.

> Python's dictionary implementation reduces the average complexity of
>   dictionary lookups to O(1) by requiring that key objects provide a
>   "hash" function.

...and lists don't fulfill this requirement:

```
hash([1, 2, 3])
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-97-0b995650570c> in <module>()
# ----> 1 hash([1, 2, 3])
# 
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have to say - your answer is better, so deleting ;)